# Prefix/Suffix highlighted text in textbox

Tags: javascript

I have to make a small javascript function that adds a prefix and suffix to a selected text within a textbox.

This is what I have so far:

```
function AddTags(name, prefix, suffix) {
    try
    {
        var textArea = document.getElementById(name).value;
        var i = 0;
        var textArray = textArea.split("\n");
        if (textArray == null) {
            document.getElementById(name).value += prefix + suffix
        }
        else {
            for (i = 0; i < textArray.length; i++) {
                textArray[i] = prefix + textArray[i] + suffix;
            }
            document.getElementById(name).value = textArray.join("\n");
        }
    }
    catch (err) { }
}
```

Now this function adds the provided prefix and suffix to every line, but I need to find out how to break up my textbox's text in `Text before selection`, `Selected text` and `Text after selection`.

Anybody any experience on this?

**EDIT:**
TriniBoy's function set me on the right track. I didn't need the whole suggestion.
This is the edited version of my original code:

```
    function AddTags(name, prefix, suffix) {
    try
    {
        var textArea = document.getElementById(name);
        var i = 0;
        var selStart = textArea.selectionStart;
        var selEnd = textArea.selectionEnd;
        var textbefore = textArea.value.substring(0, selStart);
        var selected = textArea.value.substring(selStart, selEnd);
        var textAfter = textArea.value.substring(selEnd);
        if (textAfter == "") {
            document.getElementById(name).value += prefix + suffix
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById(name).value = textbefore + prefix + selected + suffix + textAfter;
        }
    }
    catch (err) { }
}
```

Thx TriniBoy, I'll mark your leg-up as answer.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for this?

Comment: Off course: http://jsfiddle.net/PycwX/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your demo and your explanation, hopefully I got your requirements correct.

See code comments for a break down.

[See demo fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/PycwX/5/)

```
var PreSuffApp = PreSuffApp || {
selText: "",
selStart: 0,
selEnd: 0,
getSelectedText: function (id) {
    var text = "",
        docSel = document.selection, //For IE
        winSel = window.getSelection,
        P = PreSuffApp,
        textArea = document.getElementById(id);

    if (typeof winSel !== "undefined") {
        text = winSel().toString(); //Grab the current selected text
        if (typeof docSel !== "undefined" && docSel.type === "Text") {
            text = docSel.createRange().text; //Grab the current selected text
        }
    }
    P.selStart = textArea.selectionStart; //Get the start of the selection range
    P.selEnd = textArea.selectionEnd; //Get the end of the selection range
    P.selText = text; //Set the value of the current selected text
},

addTags: function (id, prefix, suffix) {
    try {
        var textArea = document.getElementById(id),
            P = PreSuffApp,
            range = P.selEnd - P.selStart; //Used to calculate the lenght of the selection

        //Check to see if some valuable text is selected
        if (P.selText.trim() !== "") {
            textArea.value = textArea.value.splice(P.selStart, range, prefix + P.selText + suffix); //Call the splice method on your text area value
        } else {
            alert("You've selected a bunch of nothingness");
        }
    } catch (err) {}
}
};

//Extend the string obj to splice the string from a start character index to an end range, like an array.
String.prototype.splice = function (index, rem, s) {
    return (this.slice(0, index) + s + this.slice(index + Math.abs(rem)));
};
```

Comment: Thx for the assist. Your code contained the commands I needed to complete the task. My edited code is put in the OP.

Comment: @FoxHound: Good stuff, happy to hear it helped out.